# What is the practical limit on the number of keys you can pass to memcache.get_multi on App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

App Engine's memcache service provides the ability to get multiple keys in one API call (`get_multi(['1', '2'])`), and although other answers here have shown that there is no hard limit imposed in memcache (the example I saw tested out getting 100,000 keys in one call), obviously there are practical limits on App Engine as the number of keys grows and latency becomes unreasonable.

Has anyone run any benchmarks showing how long it takes to retrieve multiple keys as the number of keys grows into the thousands?

Comment: Are you asking about Memcached (http://code.google.com/p/memcached/) or about the Memcache API provided in Google App Engine?

Comment: App Engine's memcache service -- just updated the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

On Google App Engine, I believe the limit should be the size of the protocol buffer encoding  the corresponding rpc, and according to the [SDK source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/memcache/memcache_stub.py&l=45): it is `32 << 20 = 32MB`

Comment: The 32 MB limit is also documented in the API docs: "The "multi" batch operations can have any number of elements. The total size of the call and the total size of the data fetched must not exceed 32 megabytes." (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits)